# Error: cannot read properties of undefined in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am trying to loop through every movie inside the movies array and render it.
There are 4 sections Trending,NewDisney,Originals,Recommended.
The movies' data is stored inside the firestore and I am retrieving it from there.
Here's the code
(All the styling is removed to make the code short here)

movieSlice.js file

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  recommend: null,
  newDisney: null,
  original: null,
  trending: null,
};

const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setMovies: (state, action) => {
      state.recommend = action.payload.recommend;
      state.newDisney = action.payload.newDisney;
      state.original = action.payload.original;
      state.trending = action.payload.trending;
    },
  },
});

export const { setMovies } = movieSlice.actions;

export const selectRecommend = (state) => state.movie.recommend;
export const selectNewdisney = (state) => state.movie.newDisney;
export const selectOriginal = (state) => state.movie.original;
export const selectTrending = (state) => state.movie.trending;

export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

Recommends.js file

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import p1 from "../images/sample_img.jpg";
import { selectRecommend } from "../features/movies/movieSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
const Recommend = () => {
  const movies = useSelector(selectRecommend);
  return (
    <Container>
      Recommended movies for you!
      <Content>
        {movies &&
          movies.map((movie, key) => {
            <Link to={"/detail/" + movie.id} key={key}>
              <Wrap imgUrl={movie.cardImg} alt={movie.title} />
            </Link>;
          })}
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Recommend;
```

Home.js file (Where all the components are imported)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ImgSlider from "./ImgSlider";
import NewDisney from "./NewDisney";
import Originals from "./Originals";
import Recommend from "./Recommends";
import Trending from "./Trending";
import Viewers from "./Viewers";
import { setMovies } from "../features/movies/movieSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import db from "../firebase";
import { selectUserName } from "../features/user/userSlice";
import { collection, query, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);

  useEffect(() => {
    let recommends = [];
    let newDisneys = [];
    let trendings = [];
    let originals = [];
    console.log("Hello!");
    const q = query(collection(db, "movies"));
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
        switch (doc.data().type) {
          case "recommend":
            recommends = [...recommends, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }];
            break;
          case "new":
            newDisneys = [...newDisneys, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }];
            break;
          case "trending":
            trendings = [...trendings, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }];
            break;
          case "originals":
            originals = [...originals, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }];
            break;
        }
      });
      dispatch(
        setMovies({
          recommend: recommends,
          trending: trendings,
          newDisney: newDisneys,
          original: originals,
        })
      );
    });
  }, [userName]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <ImgSlider />
      <Viewers />
      <Recommend />
      <NewDisney />
      <Originals />
      <Trending />
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

But unfortunately this is not working and I am getting this error for all components (Recommend,Trending,NewDisney,Originals)

```
movieSlice.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'recommend')
    at selectRecommend (movieSlice.js:26:1)
    at memoizedSelector (with-selector.development.js:79:1)
    at getSnapshotWithSelector (with-selector.development.js:134:1)
    at mountSyncExternalStore (react-dom.development.js:16799:1)
    at Object.useSyncExternalStore (react-dom.development.js:17727:1)
    at useSyncExternalStore (react.development.js:1676:1)
    at useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector (with-selector.development.js:145:1)
    at useSelector (useSelector.js:41:1)
    at Recommend (Recommends.js:8:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide full error, usually these errors are like Error: cannot read properties of undefined in react-redux, reading "SOMETHING"

Comment: There are 4 blocks of the same error each for Trending.js,Originals.js,NewDisney.js,Recommend,js. I have provided error for Recommed.js file only as you see on the 9th line  "at Recommend (Recommends.js:8:1)"

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring where you are doing this

```
export const selectRecommend = (state) => state.movie.recommend;
export const selectNewdisney = (state) => state.movie.newDisney;
export const selectOriginal = (state) => state.movie.original;
export const selectTrending = (state) => state.movie.trending;
```

Remove these and use this way to get values in App.js

```
const { recommend, newDisney, original, trending } = useSelector((state) => state.movie);
```

Comment: You mean like this const as in recommend Recommend = () => {
  const { recommend, newDisney, original, trending } = useSelector((state) => state.movie);
  const movies = recommend;
  return (
    <Container>
      Recommended movies for you!
      <Content>
        {movies &&
          movies.map((movie, key) => {
            <Link to={"/detail/" + movie.id} key={key}>
              <Wrap imgUrl={movie.cardImg} alt={movie.title} />
            </Link>;
          })}
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};  I removed what you said from movieSlice.js . But this does not work.